# How to find all child elements within a parent node using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to find all child elements within a parent webelement.

this is the parent element:

```
tableRow = element.all(by.xpath(
           "//tr[contains(@class, 'ng-scope')]" +
           "[@ng-repeat='audit in location.displayedProfileAudits']"))
          .get(0);
```

I've tried the following snippets of code, and they all fail:

```
//this fails with a timeout
var resultIcons = tableRow.all(by.xpath(".//i[contains(@class, 'icon')][contains(@ng-if, 'field.match')]"));

//this fails due to: TypeError: tableRow.element.all is not a function
var resultIcons = tableRow.element.all(by.xpath(".//i[contains(@class, 'icon')][contains(@ng-if, 'field.match')]"));

//this also times out
var resultIcons = tableRow.element(by.xpath(".//i[contains(@class, 'icon')][contains(@ng-if, 'field.match')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

@kevin. I would use CSS selector for it. Basically, almost everybody I know use CSS selector. And there are it looks incredibly easy.

For instance:

```
var resultIcons = $$('your_parent_element your_child_element'))
```

Example:

```
<bl-e-comm tag="parent">  

 <div elem="child1">....</div>
 <div elem="child1">....</div>
 <div elem="child1">....</div>
 <div elem="child1">....</div>

</bl-e-comm>
```

Your locator is:

```
var allChildElements = $$('bl-e-comm[tag="parent"] div') // $$('bl-e-comm[tag="parent"] {NOTE:here is empty space between locators} div')
```

Will collect all div elements of parent **bl-e-comm[tag="parent"]**

Read here for more options with CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

For your script convert to css selector:

```
tableRow = element.all(by.css(
        "tr[class*='ng-scope')][ng-repeat*='audit in location.displayedProfileAudits']"))
        .get(0);

var resultIcons = tableRow.element(by.css("i.icon[ng-if*='field.match']"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. That being said, I'd like to use CSS selectors more often, but I use xpath because of how familiar I am with it. 

How would i convert this xpath selector, into a css selector ? 

 expect(tableRow.element(by.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'label')][contains(@ng-bind, 'audit.status.label')]")).isPresent());

Comment: `by.css("span.label[ng-bind*='audit.status.label']")`  or `by.css("span[class*='label'][ng-bind*='audit.status.label']`